# How can I find a string in a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, string, multidimensional-array, find

I have an array that looks like this.

```
var array[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]];
```

I want to be able to search through the array for the string `"d"` and return the corresponding value `"c"`.

Comment: Will you always be matching against the *second* element of a two-element subarray?

Comment: you can create a loop then find the string on the first dimension

Comment: The "search" criterion is not clear.

Comment: `[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]].filter(function(a){return a[1]==this}, "d")[0][0]`

Comment: I have tried the find command and a number of iterative processes but I cannot separate the two elements of each item to query.

Comment: No - I want the flexibility to search for the first or second element.

Comment: what is `corresponding value` ? index, other element? Question could use more clarification

Comment: Why don't you try to parse it as a JSON object and just get the value from it then ?

Comment: @Carlos2W There is no such thing as JSON object. JSON is a _string_.

Comment: @Vohuman Obviously, but you just have to stringify it like `var json = JSON.stringify(array);`

Comment: And what's the point of doing that? Your suggestion actually makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
function find_str(array){
  for(var i in array){
    if(array[i][1] == 'd'){
      return array[i][0];
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function find_str(array){
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i][1] == 'd'){
      return array[i][0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but it returns "c,d", I want it to just return "c".

Comment: Thanks - I just found an an error in my code, fixed it and it worked.  many thanks - problem solved !

Answer (score 2):

A general function for getting all the elements of the arrays that contain the specified value. The following function uses several methods of `Array.prototype`: `filter`, `indexOf`, `map`, `slice`, `splice` and `concat` for flattening the arrays.

```
var array = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["c","e","f"]];   

function findBy(arr, val) {
    var ret = arr.filter(function(el) {
        return el.indexOf(val) > -1;
    }).map(function(el) {
       var res = el.slice();
       res.splice(el.indexOf(val), 1);
       return res;
    });
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], ret);
}

findBy(array, 'c');
// -> ["d", "e", "f"]
findBy(array, 'b');
// -> ["a"]
findBy(array, 'g');
// -> []
```