# Use the startsWith () with an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I have declared an array containing other arrays.

```
var arr = [
  [in_ar0, in_ar1, in_ar2]
  [in_ar3, in_ar4, in_ar5]
  [in_ar6, in_ar7, in_ar8]
]
```

Now, I want to print all the entries inside each position of each array that starts with the letter `'A'`.

I wrote a nested for but I'm not sure how to call the function `startsWith`. This is what I have but is not printing.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){       
    console.log(arr.startsWith('A'));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find a string in a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228691/how-can-i-find-a-string-in-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use an `if` statement so that you only print out the string that pass the `startsWith('A')` test.
2. The entry/string is accessed using `arr[i][j]` not `arr`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if(arr[i][j].startsWith('A')) {
      console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is in each array? are they array of strings?

if so- this would work..
you need to check `arr[i][j]` and not the full array..

this will print `true` for "Abc" and "Ab" and `false` for everything else...

```
  var arr = [
    ["Abc", "cde", "bcd"],
    ["ghi", "abcd", "bcda"],
    ["bac", "cdef", "Ab"],
  ];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){       
      console.log(arr[i][j].startsWith('A'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Patman.  Is something like this what you're going for?  https://jsfiddle.net/sfd40ek2/

```
var arr = [
  ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', '']
];
arr[0][0] = 'Anchovies';
arr[1][2] = 'Artichokes';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j].startsWith('A'));
  }
}
```